# #1242 error my sql

Tags: mysql

I'm writing a query and msql return me #1242 error;
here is the query, everything works fine but the issue comes from the subquery as it always give the same result instead of adapting this result depending on the usager.id

if I remove the Where clause the error appears

do you have any ideas how to fix that query ?
thank a lot

```
SELECT usager.nom,usager.prenom,usager.pseudonyme, usager.banni,COUNT( sujets.idCreateur) AS 'nb_sujets',usager.id,
  (SELECT COUNT( reponses.idUsager)
     FROM usager
     Left Join reponses ON reponses.idUsager = usager.id
  WHERE reponses.idUsager = usager.id
     GROUP by usager.id) as 'nb_reponses'
FROM usager
LEFT Join sujets ON sujets.idCreateur = usager.id
GROUP by usager.id
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Error 1242: Subquery returns more than 1 row](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/error-messages-server.html#error_er_subquery_no_1_row), is because the result list of a query can only have one value. To get response count needs to be part of the main query:

```
SELECT usager.nom,
       usager.prenom,
       usager.pseudonyme,
       usager.banni,
       COUNT( DISTINCT sujets.id) AS 'nb_sujets',
       usager.id,
       COUNT( DISTINCT reponses.id) AS nb_responses
FROM usager
LEFT JOIN sujets ON sujets.idCreateur = usager.id
LEFT JOIN reponses ON reponses.idUsager = usager.id
GROUP by usager.id
```

Comment: I've tried that query before as well but the result is not good because it puts wrong numbers in 'nb_sujets' and 'nb_responses';
it returns 12 sujets and 12 reponses for the usager number 3
instead of 4 sujets and 3 reponses

Comment: Can you create an example in [sqlfiddle.com](http://sqlfiddle.com/)

Comment: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/d9767c/4 here is the link you'll see that at the column 'nb_sujets' it's 12 everywhere 
instead of 0 4 1

Comment: thanks. edited to http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/499d21/5 and answer above. Needed to remove the `WHERE` clause (had JOIN criteria already) and `DISTINCT` on the PK of the joined table to aggregate the results per `usager.id` again rather than pthe combination of `useager` and `sujets`.)

Comment: thank a lot for your help and your time :)